# Heroku Django cant find template

Tags: django, heroku

Despite that I have  'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')], in my settings, still Heroku cant find the template. By the way Heroku finds some templates, but it seems that he cant finds those on CBV's. Any idea what might me be problem? Thank you in advance.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        # 'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

```
class InventoryView(MyLoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    template_name = 'inventory/RawMaterials.html'
    model = RawMaterial
```

this one is working on the local machine despite that the template folder is called Inventory

so I changed the template in the CBV to

```
class InventoryView(MyLoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    template_name = 'Inventory/RawMaterials.html'
    model = RawMaterial
```